# How do I find newlines in vi?

Tags: vi

How do I find all newlines in a text file in vi? In fact, I'm trying to find two newlines in succession.

For the moment I'm just trying to find single newlines:

```
:\n
```

But that gives:

```
E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &
```

Comment: `/` is the character that starts a search, not `:`. So `/\n`, or really, `/\n\n`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:` is used to enter commandos. You need the `/` (without anything in advance).

```
/\n\n
```

finds two consecutive newlines.

```
:%s/\n\n/\r/
```

replaces two consecutive newlines with a single one. Note the `\r` in the replacement section.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the search  like this :/\n

Comment: Cool! I didn't know, that `/` is a shortcut for `:/`.